# NullPointerException when I try to capture an image (built-in camera) and save it to a file

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, camera, android-camera-intent

Here's what the app does - User clicks button (to take a picture) on Activity A, the  captured image gets set as on an ImageView in Activity A, and then the user clicks a "save" button, which takes him/her to Activity B, where  the image they took gets displayed (on an ImageView in Activity B)

In order to do this I am trying to find a way to save the image. I tried many different things, but I keep getting a NullPointerException. Here is my code:

I highlighted the area where I think the error is:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.take_picture_button:
            takePic = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePic.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile(); //so photoFile = the file we created up top
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {

                    **takePic.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT**, //extra_output is just the name of the Intent-extra used to indicate a content resolver Uri to be used to store the requested image or video.
                            **Uri.fromFile(photoFile));**
                    startActivityForResult(takePic, cameraData);
                }
```

And here is the code for the onActivityResult

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == cameraData && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mReturningWithResult = true;
        extras = data.getExtras();
```

And here is where I set my image view to my captured image (on Activity A)

```
@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    if (mReturningWithResult) {
        foodImage = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        foodImageView.setImageBitmap(foodImage);
    }
    mReturningWithResult = false;//resetting it for next time

}
```

Here is the logcat (sorry I'm new to this)

```
    10-15 20:58:59.612  32005-32005/com.example.nikhil.foodshark D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode    0
10-15 20:59:21.545  32005-32005/com.example.nikhil.foodshark I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
10-15 20:59:23.127  32005-32005/com.example.nikhil.foodshark W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
10-15 20:59:33.678  32005-32005/com.example.nikhil.foodshark D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-15 20:59:33.678  32005-32005/com.example.nikhil.foodshark W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a39da0)
10-15 20:59:33.678  32005-32005/com.example.nikhil.foodshark E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.nikhil.foodshark, PID: 32005
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.nikhil.foodshark/com.example.nikhil.foodshark.NewDish}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3680)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3723)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:174)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.nikhil.foodshark.NewDish.onActivityResult(NewDish.java:144)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5650)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3676)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3723)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:174)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 20:59:56.353  32005-32005/com.example.nikhil.foodshark I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 32005 SIG: 9
10-15 20:59:56.613      378-378/com.example.nikhil.foodshark I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
10-15 20:59:56.723      378-378/com.example.nikhil.foodshark I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.050_msm8960_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.050__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
    Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.050
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
10-15 20:59:56.763      378-378/com.example.nikhil.foodshark D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Do you guys know a way I can fix this? Thank you!

Comment: What is the null pointer exception? Please post a stacktrace.

Comment: don't say _"..where I think the error is"_. the stack trace tell exactly where the error is. post it here

Comment: i don't see any highlighted areas i only see comments also post your stacktrace so we can help

Comment: Hey guys sorry Im new to this - I posted the logcat

Comment: What is NewDish line 144?

Comment: NewDish line 144 is  extras = data.getExtras(); from my onActivityResult() method

Comment: Is there something I can add or delete (other than EXTRA-OUTPUT) to make my intent not be null?

Comment: add a check for data.getExtras() to check for null- thats precaution.. also what is the extras variable??

Comment: the extras variable is a Bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`, in which case, the `intent` field in `onActivityResult` can be null.

The solution is to just use the photo file you created, and passed as `uri` in the `putExtra`

So instead of trying to get the photo file location from the intent, just use `Uri.fromFile(photoFile)`

replace

```
    extras = data.getExtras();
    ...
```

with

```
   `Uri.fromFile(photoFile)`
```

or just use `photoFile` if that is what you want...just dont rely on intent `data`

Comment: Thank you ashoke as well as everybody else who helped - I think I get it now!